# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/right-arrow-blue.svg' in '/home/bee/code/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/src'

Tags: web3js, javascript

[image]this is my javascript code(I'm new to coding):

```
import '../App.css';

function App() {

  return (
    <div>

      {/* Navbar */}

      <main className='exchange grid'>
        <section className='exchange__section--left grid'>

          {/* Markets */}

          {/* Balance */}

          {/* Order */}

        </section>
        <section className='exchange__section--right grid'>

          {/* PriceChart */}

          {/* Transactions */}

          {/* Trades */}

          {/* OrderBook */}

        </section>
      </main>

      {/* Alert */}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```